# jQuery fire function on portrait/landscape

Tags: jquery, html, css, screen-orientation

I am using jQuery to fire different css transitions for an interactive website, like *move object A to spot 1 on click*. Now these options should be different on different viewports.

While its easy to achieve this in css with classes, I do not know how to fire functions when the viewport changes from landscape to portrait. **Only an desktop screens**, there is no need for mobile devices.

So I am looking for something like

```
If "screen width" > "screen height" {
  //fire function 1, which contains something like
  $('#example').animate({ "top": "5%", "left": "50%" }, 100);
}

If "screen height" > "screen width" {
  //fire function 2, which contains something like
  $('#example').animate({ "top": "50%", "left": "5%" }, 100);
}
```

So that while I resize my browser the site always keeps displayed the best way possible (without needing to reload the page).

I found one helpful script to detect browser heights and widths down to IE6 [which you can find in my **demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kmcs7oyz/), but I am not able to make it work while resizing the browser.

I appreciate every hint or tip!

Comment: Why don't you just make the page [responsive](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this script you can get the window height and width during resize without reload using the jquery function

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    console.log('width is : ' + width);
    console.log('height is : ' + height);    
    if (height > width) {
        do something...
    }
    if (height < width) {
        do something...
    }
});
```

You can add the function you need to do during the resize

Answer (score 1):

You don't need **JavaScript!** You can use media queries:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* code for landscape goes here */
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
   /* code for portrait goes here */
}
```

To change an elements properties when the orientation is landscape and on desktop use the below media query, it will check that the screen is at least `1024px` (standard for desktops) and orientation of the screen is in landscape mode.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
     #example {
        /* rules go here */
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse, you can use css media queries for this, below is a sample

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
    Content goes here...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {    
    #test{
        background:red;
        padding:20px;
    }
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
     #test{
        background:green;
        padding:20px;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tq4g4em4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If your jQuery absolutely depends on knowing if portrait mode (e.g., manipulating widths) you can't always trust that comparing window/html/body ratios will give you the same answer as '@media (orientation: portrait).'  I have found that, depending on browser, there may be a small range where there is disagreement (curiously, Chrome is correct if making the window wider, but lags when making it narrower).

To solve this, I add a dummy (empty) div and hide it in landscape mode. Then test $(dummy div).is(':visible') to determine if the browser thinks it's in portrait mode.